# Charts for ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts

I searched on the documentation and I did not seem to find much info regarding
this subject. ( I saw some for Web Forms, but I am using MVC ).

What I want to accomplish is to get some data from the model, pass it to the view and 
create some charts from this data.

Any references or common approach to this ? Looking for some free solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Highcharts JS](http://www.highcharts.com/) for many projects.  It works well.

In your view, you can have Highcharts get your data from an Ajax action on your MVC controller that returns Json data:

```
public JsonResult GetChartData()
{
  // ...
  return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) is good for charts. You can pull data from server using Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

3rd party product is probably your best bet.  I've used [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) in the past.